# dimension table with "like" condition

Tags: database-design

In an effort to scale some existing code, we are removing logic from CASE statements and putting it in dimension/lookup tables.  Thus instead of CASE WHEN 'F' THEN 'Female' WHEN 'M' THEN 'Male' is now handled by a gender dimension.  (A very simplistic example)

But some of our CASE statements use LIKE operators, including comparison strings like `'ABC%DEF'` and `'%ABC%'`.

I am looking for suggestions on the best way to handle this.  Our fact tables have over a billion rows, and growing, so efficiency is key.  We are Oracle 11gr2, if that is applicable.

Answer (score 2):

Here are four approaches that each have advantages and disadvantages depending on what the current bottleneck is.

### Normalize by adding a surrogate key column

```
--Sql Server syntax (My Oracle knowledge seems to have 
--                   rusted due to lack of use)
CREATE TABLE orders (
  order_id int not null primary key, 
  order_date DateTime not null,
  source_code char(10) not null, 
  amount decimal(10,2) not null
)

SELECT 
    order_id, 
    CASE 
        WHEN source_code LIKE '%A11' THEN 'Acme 2011'
        WHEN source_code like '%A12' then 'Acme 2012'
    END advertising_campaign
FROM orders
```

Transforms into:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
  order_id int not null primary key, 
  order_date DateTime not null,
  source_code_key int not null,
--  source_code char(10) not null, 
  amount decimal(10,2) not null
)


CREATE TABLE source_codes (
  source_code_key int not null primary key, 
  Advertising_campaign varchar(20) not null )

INSERT INTO source_codes ( advertising_campaign)
SELECT DISTINCT 
   CASE 
        WHEN source_code LIKE '%A11' THEN 'Acme 2011'
        WHEN source_code like '%A12' then 'Acme 2012'
    END advertising_campaign
FROM orders

SELECT 
    order_id, 
    source_codes.advertising_campaign
FROM orders INNER JOIN source_codes 
            ON orders.source_code_key = source_codes.key
```

This approach is **the cleanest from a pure dimensional modeling perspective**. The logic in your CASE statements would be applied in an ETL process and the size on disk is reduced.  In Sql Server the CPU overhead is increased because a join is typically more cpu intensive then a CASE statement (I assume this is also true for Oracle).  ***If I/O is the bottleneck then this is a trade-off worth making and is the preferred approach.***

### Join on Business Key to Lookup table

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
  order_id int not null primary key, 
  order_date DateTime not null,
  source_code char(10) not null, 
  amount decimal(10,2) not null
)


CREATE TABLE source_codes (
  source_code char(10) not null primary key, 
  Advertising_campaign varchar(20) not null )

INSERT INTO source_codes (source_code, advertising_campaign)
SELECT DISTINCT 
    source_code, 
    CASE 
        WHEN source_code LIKE '%A11' THEN 'Acme 2011'
        WHEN source_code like '%A12' then 'Acme 2012'
    END advertising_campaign
FROM orders

SELECT 
    order_id, 
    source_codes.advertising_campaign
FROM orders INNER JOIN source_codes 
            ON orders.source_code = source_codes.source_code
```

This approach would require one row in source_codes for each distinct source_code.  Size on disk increases due to source_codes table.  Disk IO remains the same or increases depending on the ability of the source_codes table to fit in memory.  ***This approach makes sense only in the case where the queries are CPU bound due to logic in the CASE statement that is horrendously complex.***

### Keep Existing Schema

If the bottleneck is the CPU and *the cost of computing the CASE statements is less than the cost of joining to a another table* then ***keeping your existing queries may be the best bet***.

### Keep Existing Schema + Move CASE logic into client application/reporting tool

This approach makes sense **if the bottleneck is network bandwidth to the client** or the CPU load is **too high with either the JOIN or the CASE statements**.  By moving the complex CASE logic off the server you can distribute CPU load.  This would be ***the most intrusive solution and should be considered last resort***.